# How can I change the LogLevel for AWS ElastiCache Redis engine logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I want to look at my Redis logs. Unfortunamely using AWS ElastiCache seems to make this difficult. I want to be able to be able to see information on connections, etc.

I upgraded my engine version to 7.0.7 since the ability to access logs wasn't enabled until a few versions of engine version 6.x. That made the log tab appear and I was able to configure my Redis cluster to log to CloudWatch. After some time, logs appeared. Each entry has the "LogLevel" field set to "NOTICE". Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Log_Delivery.html) a `VERBOSE("-")` level exists and I'd like to use that.

I cannot find that in the web-UI. I tried using the redis-cli, but ran into [this issue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html). AWS doesn't allow editing the config from redis-cli.

The [ElastiCache API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyCacheCluster.html) doesn't mention log level.

How do I see more logs? Looks like I can use the redis-cli `monitor` command, but a scroll as I desire log file would be idea.

Comment: You explicitly asking about `loglevel`, but from your question I understand you might be looking for data that might be available to you from CloudWatch metrics. Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 0):

In ElastiCache, the `loglevel` config is set to `notice`. At the time of writing, there's no option to change the `loglevel` config in ElastiCache for Redis.

As for configuration changes to Redis in general - ElastiCache does restrict the `CONFIG` command. However, ElastiCache still allows changing a subset of configurations through [parameter groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Creating.html).